# how to solve the pyspark installing problem

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have tried all I can to install the Spark to my MAC. I want to use Jpyter Notebook to use the Spark but I just found it frustrating to install it.

What I have tried:

1. brew install apache-spark--> not working

   ```
   Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
   DownloadError: Failed to download resource "apache-spark"
   Download failed: Couldn't determine mirror, try again later.
   ```
2. install the package from online and unzip to my root and use the following 
   export SPARK_HOME=/Users/myname/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7 
   export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

when I run pyspark in the bash, the following:

```
    Error executing Jupyter command'/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/find_spark_home.py': 
   [Errno 2] No such file or directory/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 77: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory

  /Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Does it mean that my SPARK_HOME setting is not working? How should I just type in "pyspark" in my bash to run pyspark through jupyter notebook?

I have also updated the info in nano .bash_profile as following:

```
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

My Python 3 is in anaconda environment, any suggestions?